# If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number, then what is the optimal constant $C$ such that $\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} < \frac{m^2 - p^k}{C}$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

The question is as is in the title:

> If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then what is the optimal constant $C$ such that $$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} < \frac{m^2 - p^k}{C}?$$

(Note that the special prime $p$ satisfies $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.)

**MY OWN PROOF FOR $C = 1$**

It is trivial to show that $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  This implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} \neq m^2 - p^k$$
since $\sigma(m^2)/p^k$ is always odd.

Now, suppose to the contrary that
$$\sigma(m^2) > p^k m^2 - p^{2k}.$$
$$p^{2k} + \sigma(m^2) > p^k m^2$$
$$2p^{2k} + 2\sigma(m^2) > 2p^k m^2 = \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2)$$
$$2p^{2k} > \sigma(m^2)\bigg(\sigma(p^k) - 2\bigg)$$
$$\sigma(m^2) < \frac{2p^{2k}}{\sigma(p^k) - 2} \leq \frac{2p^{2k}}{p^k - 1}$$
where we have used the lower bound $\sigma(p^k) \geq p^k + 1$.
But from the paper [Dris (2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), we have the lower bound
$$3p^k \leq \sigma(m^2)$$
while we also have the upper bound
$$\frac{2p^{2k}}{p^k - 1} = 2(p^k + 1) + \frac{2}{p^k - 1}.$$

This implies that
$$3p^k < 2(p^k + 1) + \frac{2}{p^k - 1}$$
$$p^k - 2 < \frac{2}{p^k - 1}$$
$$(p^k - 1)(p^k - 2) < 2.$$
This last inequality is a contradiction, as $p^k \geq 5$.

We therefore conclude that the inequality
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} < \frac{m^2 - p^k}{C}$$
holds when $C=1$.

> Does the inequality still hold when the constant $C > 1$?  If so, then what is the optimal value for $C$?

Comment: I am accepting @mathlove's answer for now.  If somebody else would be able to show that $C=2$ (or even $C=3$) is possible, then I would switch to that answer as the accepted one, provided it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Last updated on March 2, 2021 - 5:04 PM Manila time*)

Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.

Suppose to the contrary that
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} > \frac{m^2 - p^k}{C}$$
and that $C=3$.

Following in the footsteps of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3931083/28816), we have
$$3\sigma(m^2) > p^k m^2 - p^{2k}$$
$$6\sigma(m^2) + 2p^{2k} > 2p^k m^2 = \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2)$$
$$2p^{2k} > \sigma(m^2)\bigg(\sigma(p^k) - 6\bigg)$$
Assuming $\sigma(p^k) \neq 6$ (that is, assuming it is **not the case** that $p=5$ and $k=1$ holds), then
$$\sigma(m^2) < \frac{2p^{2k}}{\sigma(p^k) - 6} \leq \frac{2p^{2k}}{p^k - 5} = \frac{2p^{2k} - 50}{p^k - 5} + \frac{50}{p^k - 5} = 2(p^k + 5) + \frac{50}{p^k - 5}.$$

But according to [Broughan et al. (2013)](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf), we have the lower bound $315p^k \leq \sigma(m^2)$.

This implies that
$$315p^k < 2(p^k + 5) + \frac{50}{p^k - 5}$$
$$(313p^k - 10)(p^k - 5) < 50$$
which is clearly a contradiction if $p \neq 5$ or $k \neq 1$.

We therefore have the following proposition:

> If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ satisfying $\sigma(p^k) \neq 6$, then
> $$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} \leq \frac{m^2 - p^k}{3}.$$

---

**SECOND ATTEMPT**

Using [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967)'s approach in his/her answer below, together with [Broughan et al. (2013)](https://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf)'s result, we have the lower bound $\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} \geq 315$.
As in mathlove's answer, let the quantity $F$ be given by
$$F = \frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2} - \frac{p^{2k}}{\sigma(m^2)} \geq \frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2} - \frac{p^k}{315} = \frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{2(p-1)} - \frac{p^k}{315} := f_1(k).$$
Since $f_1(k)$ is increasing, we get
$$F \geq f_1(k) \geq f_1(1) = \frac{p+1}{2} - \frac{p}{315} \geq \frac{188}{63} \approx 2.98412698412698$$
whence we have the following proposition:

> If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then
> $$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} \leq \frac{m^2 - p^k}{\frac{188}{63}}.$$

---

**THIRD ATTEMPT**

Using mathlove's approach in his/her answer below, together with mathlove's [answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4028814/28816), we have the lower bound $\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} \geq 3^3 \times 5^3 = 3375$.
As in mathlove's answer, let the quantity $F$ be given by
$$F = \frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2} - \frac{p^{2k}}{\sigma(m^2)} \geq \frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2} - \frac{p^k}{3375} = \frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{2(p-1)} - \frac{p^k}{3375} := f_2(k).$$
Since $f_2(k)$ is increasing, we get
$$F \geq f_2(k) \geq f_2(1) = \frac{p+1}{2} - \frac{p}{3375} \geq \frac{2024}{675} = 2.99\overline{851}$$
whence we have the following proposition:

> If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then
> $$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} \leq \frac{m^2 - p^k}{\frac{2024}{675}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer.

> Does the inequality still hold when the constant $C > 1$?

Yes, one can get
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} \le \frac{m^2 - p^k}{\color{red}{4/3}}\tag1$$

I don't know if this is the optimal value for $C$.

*Proof for $(1)$* :

Note that $$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} < \frac{m^2 - p^k}{C}\iff \frac{p^k(m^2 - p^k)}{\sigma(m^2)}\gt C$$

Let $F:=\dfrac{p^k(m^2 - p^k)}{\sigma(m^2)}$. We can write $F$ as

$$F=\frac{p^k(m^2 - p^k)\sigma(p^k)}{\sigma(m^2)\sigma(p^k)}=\frac{p^k(m^2 - p^k)\sigma(p^k)}{2p^km^2}=\frac{m^2\sigma(p^k)-p^{k}\sigma(p^k)}{2m^2}$$

$$=\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}-\frac{p^{k}\sigma(p^k)}{2m^2}=\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}-\frac{p^{2k}}{\sigma(m^2)}$$

Using $3p^k\le \sigma(m^2)$, we get

$$F=\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}-\frac{p^{2k}}{\sigma(m^2)}\ge \frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}-\frac{p^{k}}{3}=\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{2(p-1)}-\frac{p^{k}}{3}=\frac{p^{k+1}+2p^k-3}{6(p-1)}$$

Let $g(k):=\dfrac{p^{k+1}+2p^k-3}{6(p-1)}$. Since $g(k)$ is increasing, we get
$$F\ge g(k)\ge g(1)=\frac{p+3}{6}\ge \frac{5+3}{6}=\frac 43$$
to have
$$F\ge \frac 43$$
which is equivalent to $(1)$.$\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: Does $C=2$ not work, @mathlove?

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : I don't know if $C=2$ works.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.

Suppose to the contrary that
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} > \frac{m^2 - p^k}{C}$$
and that $C=2$.

(Note that
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} \neq \frac{m^2 - p^k}{2}$$
since the LHS is odd while the RHS is even, as $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.)

Following in the footsteps of the proof in the OP, we have
$$2\sigma(m^2) > p^k m^2 - p^{2k}$$
$$4\sigma(m^2) + 2p^{2k} > 2p^k m^2 = \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2)$$
$$2p^{2k} > \sigma(m^2)\bigg(\sigma(p^k) - 4\bigg)$$
(Note that, since $p$ is the special prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $p^k \geq 5$, so that $\sigma(p^k) \geq p^k + 1 \geq 6$.  This shows that the factor $\bigg(\sigma(p^k) - 4\bigg)$ is always positive.)
This implies that
$$\sigma(m^2) < \frac{2p^{2k}}{\sigma(p^k) - 4} \leq \frac{2p^{2k}}{p^k - 3}$$
where we have used the lower bound $\sigma(p^k) \geq p^k + 1$.
But the upper bound can be rewritten as
$$\frac{2p^{2k}}{p^k - 3} = \frac{2p^{2k} - 18}{p^k - 3} + \frac{18}{p^k - 3} = 2(p^k + 3) + \frac{18}{p^k - 3}.$$
However, as before, we have the lower bound $3p^k \leq \sigma(m^2)$.  This implies that
$$3p^k < 2(p^k + 3) + \frac{18}{p^k - 3}$$
which means that
$$(p^k - 6)(p^k - 3) < 18,$$
an inequality that is satisfied when $p=5$ and $k=1$.

We infer that we need to use a larger lower bound for $\sigma(m^2)/p^k$.  We use the one by [Dris and Luca (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1437):
$$7p^k \leq \sigma(m^2) < 2(p^k + 3) + \frac{18}{p^k - 3}$$
$$(5p^k - 6)(p^k - 3) < 18.$$
This is a contradiction as $p^k \geq 5$ implies that
$$(5p^k - 6)(p^k - 3) \geq 38.$$

We therefore have the following proposition:

> If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then
> $$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} < \frac{m^2 - p^k}{2}.$$