# On the inequality $\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} < \frac{n^2 - q^k}{C}$ where $C>1$ and $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number - Part II

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This is a continuation of this [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3920469).)

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  (In particular, we know that $q \geq 5$.)

Denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, and the *sum of aliquot/proper divisors* of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$.  Finally, denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

In [this accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3931095/28816) to a closely related question, it was proved that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} \leq \frac{n^2 - q^k}{\frac{188}{63}}.$$

Since we also have, in general, the following equation and inequalities
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} \leq \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q} \leq D(n^2),$$
here is my:

> **QUESTION**: If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, is the following inequality true in general?
> $$D(n^2) \leq \frac{n^2 - q^k}{\frac{188}{63}}$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

The inequality under consideration in the question is equivalent to
$$376n^2 - 188\sigma(n^2) \leq 63n^2 - 63q^k.$$
Suppose to the contrary that it is false.  This implies that
$$I(n^2) < \frac{313}{188} + \frac{63q^k}{188n^2}.$$
But we have the estimate
$$\frac{q^k}{n^2} < \frac{2}{315}$$
by [Broughan, Delbourgo, and Zhou (2013)](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf), which implies that
$$\frac{2(q-1)}{q} < I(n^2) < \frac{313}{188} + \frac{63q^k}{188n^2} < \frac{313}{188} + \frac{63}{188}\cdot\frac{2}{315} = \frac{1567}{940},$$
from which it follows that
$$q < \frac{1880}{313} \approx 6.00639.$$
Since $q$ is a prime which satisfies $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $q=5$.  Alas, this is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true in general.

Using $$D(n^2)=2n^2-\sigma(n^2)=2n^2-\frac{2q^kn^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=2n^2-\frac{2q^kn^2(q-1)}{q^{k+1}-1}$$
we see that
$$D(n^2) \leq \dfrac{n^2 - q^k}{188/63}$$ is equivalent to $$(63q^{k+1}-376q^k+313)n^2\ge 63q^k(q^{k+1}-1)$$
which does not hold when $q=5$ and $k\gt 1$ since then LHS is negative.

Comment: My profuse thanks as well for this other answer, @mathlove!  +1 and accept =)